# Jquery Autocomplete Help

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a select box and a textbox, soon I type something I would like to take the value of the select box when autocomplete starts fetching from the server. how could that be possible.

Regards
Dixanta Shrestha
dixanta@creatorsnepal.com

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [jQuery Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

You can specify a custom function to execute on "start", "send", "stop", "success" events of the call, as shown in the events examples in that page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "...",
    data: { ... },
    success : function(returnedData){
         ...
    },
    error : ...
    ...
```

To get the value of the select element, you can do:

```
var myVar=$("#selectElementId").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need this plug in installed
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are already using the [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin (if not, get it). If you want to send the value of the select with the autocomplete request, you can use a function for the extraParams option for the autocomplete plugin to extract the value and send it with.

```
$('#textbox').autocomplete( '/url', {
    ... other options ...
    extraParams: function() { return $('selectbox').serialize(); },
    ... more options ...
});
```